# Overlay Help Tips with jQuery

Tags: jquery, overlay, modal-dialog

I would like to create an overlay layer that pops up if a user clicks a 'help' link that displays help tips (most likely a `.png` image) pointing out elements of the website.

I've seen this done on other websites (although I can't currently find one) whereby there is a semi-transparent overlay over the entire page whereby help tips are shown. I would then like the overlay to disappear if the user clicks or click on a 'close' button.

I understand that is a lot to ask, but if anyone could point me in the right direction, or to an online tutorial, etc. I'd REALLY appreciate it :)

Here is an example of the effect I want to create on my website:
[image: jquery overlay website help tips]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at Impromptu plugin

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Comment: I like the 'tour' feature at the bottom, but it doesn't seem to give you the markup needed to implement? (or am i missing something?)

Comment: Impromptu Tour is exactly what I wanted. Now I'm having another issue though... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653471/css-overlay-effect-exclude-certain-container

Comment: If you're looking for tour plugins, i highly recommend zurb's [jQuery Joyride website tour plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin).  Otherwise @guilleva's answer is exactly what you're looking for!

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at [Chardin.js](http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/), it's pretty nice and easy to implement

Answer (score 3):

Another good plugin seems to be chardin 
http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to learn how to create an **overlay**. That's easily done with a bit of elementary CSS.

The stuff that show the help stuff (your PNG images) are going to be contained inside the overlay element (which is most probably a `div`). You're going to have to position them around, and you can choose to do that with pure CSS, or use something like jQuery UI's [Position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) helper to help you out.

Lastly, you're going to need a bit of Javascript / jQuery to kick off the toggling of the overlay. You want to read up [on events in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Most probably, you're going to be attaching on `click`.

Comment: If you don't understand it, I'll be glad to explain it a bit more. The others are suggesting plugins; I'm trying to tell you how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something like [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)