# CSS Overlay Effect - Exclude certain container

Tags: css, overlay

I am applying an overlay effect to a webpage with the CSS shown here:

```
.jqifade{
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #000000; 
    height:2315px !important; /*set to page height*/
}
```

This CSS overlays the entire webpage with a color (black) which is later set to 30% opacity with JS. I would like to exclude a div with `id="noOverlay"` so that the CSS is NOT applied to this div. Is this possible? And if so... how??

Comment: You don't want the css to be applied to a container or you want a container to be visible over the overlay?

Comment: @Litek think he wants it that div to be on top of the overlay so it is not covered by it since he set the height to 2.3k

Comment: can you post related html or a sample of it, this problem could be solved with z-index probably but we wll have to see some code

Comment: @Huangism - That sounds like it would work - If I could move (with jQuery) a certain container over the overlay... Have any code for me?

Comment: well basically when you the overlay happens which I don't know when, you can set the z-index of that div. you can probably get away with setting the z-index in the css originally

Comment: OK i know that the z-index places items in 'stacked' order... but when I edit the z-index of the container, it doesn't seem to go to the top..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to make the z-index of that certain element higher than the overlay. Also for the overlay you might consider using rgba for the opacity.

```
.jqifade{
    position: relative; 
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3); 
    height:2315px !important; /*set to page height*/
}
```

Just watch for browser compatibility with this.

Comment: How would I make the z-index higher for that element?
and what is the benefit of using rgba over hex? I'm already controlling the opacity.

Comment: The overlay would have something like a z-index:1 and the element on top something like z-index:2-9999. The advantage of RGBa vs Opacity is that with RGBa the opacity is not inherited if you have child elements, but with Opacity it is inherited through all child elements. I guess the way I viewed the question I thought RGBa would be a better choice but that is really up to you depending on what you want.

Comment: When the jQuery generates the overlay element, it sets the z-index to 998, so I tried setting the z-index of the container to 9999 just to be safe (as I did in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bTxng/4/) but it does not work on my site... why?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is removing class *jqifade* from div with id *noOverlay*:

```
$("#noOverlay").removeClass("jqifade").
```

Or use CSS3 :not selector (works in all modern browsers):

```
.jqifade:not(#noOverlay) {}
```

EDIT:
Another solution: apply css styles using jQuery:

```
$(".jqifade:not(#noOverlay)").css(...)
```

Comment: i don't think he is adding the class to all his elements

Comment: the `jqifade` is not a class that dims the opacity, it is a 'layer' of color applied over every element. I'd like to use something similar to z-index to put the container 'on top' of the overlay, but can't seem to get it to work :(